# What is the toolchain upload that happens at the start of every release cycle?

Tags: development

Looking at the release schedules, every release seems to start with a toolchain upload.

What is a toolchain and which packages build the toolchain in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The toolchain is the set of packages which are used to build all the rest, such as `gcc`, `binutils`, `glibc`, etc. They are uploaded at the beginning of the release cycle before other packages, so that all subsequent package uploads are built against these.

Answer (score 2):

The toolchain is the programming tools for that release of Ubuntu. The developers need these tools in order to create programs for that release.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean create programs for that release? what exactly constitute a release?  As I understand the packages can be updated in given release and dependencies are modified to account for that